# BinaryTree class with extra methods

Tags: java, classes, tree

I am taking a data structures course.  I would like to check whether my `BinaryTree` code is perfect, fine or has lots of mistakes.

I would like any kind of advice on this code so I can learn from my mistakes (syntax, techniques, style, etc...).

**Note: This is not a binary search tree.**

`BinaryTree` class:

```
/**
 *  @uniersity  Saint Joseph's University
 *  @college    College of Arts and Sciences
 *  @department Computer Science
 *  @course     CSC 550: Object Oriented Design & Data Structures
 */

package mih1406.csc550.trees;
import java.io.Serializable;

// To make life easier...
// <E extends Integer> to simplify it if any method requires Integer
// eg: getSum, countLessThan
public class BinaryTree<E extends Integer> implements Serializable {
    // Inner Class
    protected class Node<E extends Integer> implements Serializable {
        protected E data;
        protected Node<E> left;
        protected Node<E> right;

        public Node(E data) {
            this.data = data;

            left = null;
            right = null;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return data.toString();
        }
    }

    // Data Fields
    protected Node<E> root;

    // Constructors
    public BinaryTree() {
        root = null;
    }

    protected BinaryTree(Node<E> root) {
        this.root = root;
    }

    public BinaryTree(E data, BinaryTree<E> leftTree,
                                      BinaryTree<E> rightTree) {
        root = new Node(data);
        if(leftTree == null || leftTree.root == null)
            root.left = null;
        else
            root.left = leftTree.root;

        if(rightTree == null || rightTree.root == null)
            root.right = null;
        else
            root.right = rightTree.root;
    }

    // Methods
    public BinaryTree<E> getLeftSubtree() {
        if(root == null)
            return new BinaryTree<E>(null);
        else
            return new BinaryTree<E>(root.left);
    }

    public BinaryTree<E> getRightSubtree() {
        if(root == null)
            return new BinaryTree<E>(null);
        else
            return new BinaryTree<E>(root.right);
    }

    public E getData() {
        if(root == null)
            return null;
        else
            return root.data;
    }

    public boolean isLeaf() {
        if(root == null)
            return false;
        else {
            if(root.left == null && root.right == null)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.append("Pre-Order Traversal:\n");
        preOrderTraversal(root, 1, sb);
        sb.append("\n");

        sb.append("In-Order Traversal:\n");
        inOrderTraversal(root, 1, sb);
        sb.append("\n");

        sb.append("Post-Order Traversal:\n");
        postOrderTraversal(root, 1, sb);

        return sb.toString();
    }

    private void preOrderTraversal(Node<E> node, int depth,
                                             StringBuilder sb) {
        for(int i = 1; i < depth; i++)
            sb.append(".");

        if(node == null) {
            sb.append("null\n");
            return;
        }

        sb.append(node.data);
        sb.append("\n");
        preOrderTraversal(node.left, depth + 1, sb);
        preOrderTraversal(node.right, depth + 1, sb);
    }

    private void inOrderTraversal(Node<E> node, int depth,
                                             StringBuilder sb) {
        if(node == null) {
            for(int i = 1; i < depth; i++)
                sb.append(".");

            sb.append("null\n");
            return;
        } else {
            inOrderTraversal(node.left, depth + 1, sb);
            for(int i = 1; i < depth; i++)
                sb.append(".");

            sb.append(node.data);
            sb.append("\n");
            inOrderTraversal(node.right, depth + 1, sb);
        }
    }

    private void postOrderTraversal(Node<E> node, int depth,
                                             StringBuilder sb) {
        if(node == null) {
            for(int i = 1; i < depth; i++)
                sb.append(".");

            sb.append("null\n");
            return;
        } else {
            postOrderTraversal(node.left, depth + 1, sb);
            postOrderTraversal(node.right, depth + 1, sb);
            for(int i = 1; i < depth; i++)
                sb.append(".");

            sb.append(node.data);
            sb.append("\n");
        }
    }

    // Gets the height of the tree
    public int getHeight() {
        return getHeight(root);
    }

    private int getHeight(Node<E> node) {
        if(node == null)
            return 0;
        else {
            int L = getHeight(node.left);
            int R = getHeight(node.right);

            return Math.max(L, R) + 1;
        }
    }

    // Gets the sum of all nodes in the tree
    public int getSum() {
        return getSum(root);
    }

    private int getSum(Node<E> node) {
        if(node == null)
            return 0;

        int S = node.data;
        int L = getSum(node.left);
        int R = getSum(node.right);

        return S + L + R;
    }

    // Counts how many items less than the given target
    public int countLessThan(E target) {
        return countLessThan(root, target);
    }

    private int countLessThan(Node<E> node, E target) {
        if(node == null)
            return 0;
        else {
            int S = (node.data < target) ? 1 : 0;
            // or int S = (node.data.compareTo(target) < 0) ? 1 : 0;
            int L = countLessThan(node.left, target);
            int R = countLessThan(node.right, target);

            return S + L + R;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Tests goes here of course :)
    }

    // The following methods *should* produce the same
    // result as their identically named ones with the class
    // BinaryTree, but they cannot access nodes directly

    // Gets the sum of all nodes in the tree
    public static int getSum(BinaryTree<Integer> T) {
        if(T.getData() == null)
            return 0;

        int S = T.getData();
        int L = getSum(T.getLeftSubtree());
        int R = getSum(T.getRightSubtree());

        return S + L + R;
    }

    // Counts how many items less than the given target
    public static int countLessThan(BinaryTree<Integer> T, int target) {
        if(T == null || T.getData() == null)
            return 0;
        else {
            int S = (T.getData() < target) ? 1 : 0;
            // or int S = (T.getData().compareTo(target) < 0) ? 1 : 0;
            int L = countLessThan(T.getLeftSubtree(), target);
            int R = countLessThan(T.getRightSubtree(), target);

            return S + L + R;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In terms of generics, there should be no reason why you would be bounding it by `Integer` (which is `final` and doesn't make sense) -- it should be bounded by `Number` (`public class BinaryTree<E extends Number>`) instead.  Your inner class shouldn't need generics, if it does for some reason it shouldn't be hiding it (e.g. `Node<T>` vs `Node<E>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good start.  Here's what I have to say about it.

- There really is no point in making `E` constrained on `Integer`.  The Integer class is `final` so it can't be anything but an `Integer`.  Either remove that constraint or remove the use of generics here and make it an `Integer`.
- Your inner class could be made static.  A node here doesn't need the outer class to mean anything and can exist on its own.
- Pretty much all members in your classes that are `protected` probably should be `private`.  Don't get into the habit of using `protected` over `private` just because.  Only do it because you *intend* for it to be overridden or used in a derived class.
- Personally, I wouldn't allow for the possibility of having a null root node.  It will help simplify your code so you don't have to put null checks everywhere you need to operate on the root.
- Your `toString()` method should return a string representation of a single tree.  What you have there (and in other related methods) is the kind of code I would expect to see in a "printTree" method.  It doesn't belong there.
- Consider making your different traversal methods either return an iterator that iterates over the nodes in the appropriate order or use them to apply the visitor pattern on what operations you want to do on your tree.  It would make them more useful in general rather than just only for filling a string buffer.
- Local variables should be in camelCase at most, not Capitalized.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has the trees be mostly immutable, which is a good idea, but to be more elegant, you should

1. Make all fields `final`.
2. Use `null` for leaves, and change the `Node` constructor to take the data and left and right.
3. `isLeaf` should be true just for `root=null`, and all accessors on leaves should (implicitly or explicitly) throw a `NPE`.
4. As previous commentators have said: get rid of useless generics (best, get rid of `extends Integer`), implement real iterators for traversals and fix `toString`.  You can then write `sum` using an iterator.
5. Write `equals(Object)` and `hashCode()`.